# What is File’s owner in XIB in this case?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib, custom-component

I've searched for similar questions for quite a while, most of which mentioned UIViewController's xib stuff.  *I tried to add a xib file for my custom  viewController model,and found that its Xib’s File’s Owner should be my custom viewController model's class--that is reasonable.  But why the situation differs when i create a xib for my UIView model*-- an example as follows:

I create my UIView model which named "KWView"(KWView.h and KWView.m)
then i  create  xib for this model, initializing it by

```
 KWView *oneView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KWView" owner:nil options:nil ]lastObject];
```

This Xib’s File’s Owner name is “NSObject”**（then i try any other more,whatever i choose, it runs smoothly）**,and there, i choose the view’s Custom Class as “KWView”[This xib named "KWView.xib"]

Questions are :

**1.Whatever i change the Xib’s File’s Owner name of my custom view, it works.  If so, what the work does this  File’s Owner do here, or saying, why can this happen?**

**2.Generally， should i set the custom view's Xib’s File’s Owner  to my custom view's class  or  the viewController's class which this view is going to be added to ?  or just set it "NSObject"?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to your question depends how you intend to extract the view from the nib at nib-load time. You are going to extract it, as you have helpfully shown us, like this:

```
KWView *oneView = 
    [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KWView" owner:nil options:nil]
        lastObject];
```

That means you aren't using the `owner:` for anything here — it is `nil`. Therefore you can leave the nib's file's owner at NSObject.

The purpose of the File's Owner is to permit you to establish, in the nib, Action and Outlet connections between the view (or its subviews) and the object that will be the *real* owner at load time — like a view controller (owner) and its `view` (the main view of the view controller). But in your case, there is no such real owner and no such Action or Outlet connections.

Comment: And for a lot more detail on the nib-loading process, see my discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_nib_loading_and_file_8217_s_owner

Comment: This confused me for a long time..  I am a freshman in iOS. Thx a lot，You did me a big favor！