# How to access custom view properties after initialize

Tags: ios, swift

I'm targeting IOS 8+.

I have a form that is used in more than one place. So I decided to create a custom view where I define the various "form" text fields.

I have built my XIB, and the UIView subclass contains the outlets for each textField.

The view is composed of a background image and a scroll with the form fields over it.

Now, my first obstacle was: I need to have this custom view in a container that may or may not have a navigation bar. This made me create a constraint outlet so I could update its value to push down the scroller view. This way I'd have the whole image in the frame, the top being behind the navbar and the scroller bellow the nav bar).

Here's a manual drawing to help understanding the problem.
[image]

It's very possible that I'm making a lot of mess and confusion on my way to solve this. :)

The problem is:

After awakeFromNib runs I have no access to the constraint property. I then noticed the same thing happens for the TextFields outlets.

So, how can I access the custom view's properties when I instantiate them programatically?

Something like:

Controller:

```
let customView = SignupView(frame: f)
view.addSubview(customView)
customView.pushScrollerDownBy(50.0)
```

Custom view:

```
func pushScrollerDownBy(yOffset: CGFloat) {
    //topScrollerConstraint is the outlet for the textField.
    topScrollerConstraint.constant = yOffset //right now topScrollerConstraint is nil. 
}
```

Comment: I think you connected topScrollerConstraint to file's owner while you connected your view to the view itself. can you check this?

Comment: Thank you Nick! That was the problem. Damn! I had connected the CustomView.swift file as the view's class, instead of the file owner. Wouldn't catch that one alone I guess.

Comment: great, will post it as an answer for future reference :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if you have connected your `topScrollerConstraint` to the file's owner since it will not get instantiated and therefore, error. Here is a recent SO question regarding difference between these two:

[What is File’s owner in XIB in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334129/what-is-file-s-owner-in-xib-in-this-case)